# Rpi I2C with I2C isolator

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, digital-isolator

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B and I want to use I2C to communicate with an Xsens MTi-2 sensor. This sensor requires fast mode of I2C and clock stretching.

If I connect the Xsens MTi-2 sensor directly to my R-Pi, as they suggest in their schema (see https://mtidocs.xsens.com/interfaces$i2c) , it works - I can communicate, get data etc!

Now, I want to use an I2C isolator in-between. If I use the MIKROE-4467 (https://www.mikroe.com/i2c-isolator-3-click) between my sensor and RPi and removing the pull-up resistors used before, I can not communicate with the sensor anymore.
Then, I decided to take just the I2C isolator chip from the MIKROE-4467, i.e., the CPC5902, and try it with different sets of pull-ups:

- no pull-up
- 2k7 pull-up only in side A (R-Pi)
- 2k7 pull-up only in side B (sensor)
- 10k in side A (R-Pi) and 2k7 pull-up in side B (sensor).
- 820 in side A (R-Pi) and 560 pull-up in side B (sensor).
- 820 in both sides.

None of these configurations worked.

At first, I was trying an isolated power supplies in sides A and B. Then I decided to use the same supply power in both sides (to simplify the problem finding). I also used a decoupling capacitor in sides A and B at first, but then I removed then as well. Also these changes did not help.

The supply voltage is 3.3V in any case, in both sides.

What could I do to get it working using and I2C isolator? Is the problem a pull-up issue or a capacitance?

EDIT: duplicated from https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2049467

Comment: Please show a schematic indicating where the pull-ups you tried were connected.

Comment: Note that the datasheet for the CPC5902 says "Side B Fast-mode I2C Compliant VDDB > 4.5V". It likely won't work in fast mode @ 3.3V.

Comment: Hey @DaveTweed, that is truth! But the datasheet later says "For VDDB supply levels below 4.5V the CPC5902 outputs are only rated for 3mA but can be operated at Fast-mode speeds of 400kb/s whenever the bus capacitive loading CLOAD <= 200pF". Maybe this is a too restrictive? How do I know if my sensor and R-Pi are 3 or 6mA, if the datasheet does not say anything about that?

Comment: I don't know. Bi-directional isolators like these can be quite finicky. When pulling down, they need to pull to a higher "low" voltage than the device to which they are connected in order to avoid latch-up, and this puts some constraints on bus capacitance and pullup resistor values.

Comment: I don't think the sensor requires fast mode. Clock stretching is also not mentioned on the page you link, not many devices require it. The page contents is also quite poor for a data sheet. But anyway, the isolator does not support fast mode at 3.3V so you can't use fast mode between two 3.3V devices.

Comment: For the records: I switched from MIKROE-4467 (https://www.mikroe.com/i2c-isolator-3-click) to Adafruit 4903 (https://www.adafruit.com/product/4903) as the board to act as I2C isolator.

Then it worked.

However, I have the feeling that it works better when the I2C isolator is a specific side than the other side. In the side that does not work that good, I was getting frequently issues in the I2C data (but it could also be that a physical connection thing, as everything is pretty quickly done).

Thank you for your support.